# QGIS Print Composer with ESPG:32615

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer

I have imported a PostGIS layer as the only object into my project and set the project and layer CRS to EPSG:32615 (UTM Zone 15N).  My layer appears just fine in the work area.  When I try to create a print composer, I cannot get the map to appear in the print composer, even though I click the `Set to map canvas extent` button in the composer.  The print composer only shows a blank, white area.  If I set the project CRS to EPSG:4326 I can add the map to the print composer.

Is there a setting I need to change to adjust to CRS of the print composer?

**EDIT**
Following some advice, I created a layer and manually added a polygon.  I noticed the issue pops up when I try to place the polygon near the origin. If the polygon is hundreds of thousands of meters from the origin, when I add the map to the print composer, things work fine.  If I place the polygon around the origin (positive and negative x and y values), the print composer seems not to like it.  With the linked file, I noticed that if I changed the scale of `Print Composer 3` to 32 or less a zoomed in version of the polygon appears.  Anything higher than 32 gives me a blank page.

Test File: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-SpdXvKI1JgX1lGbnFDMWFxRHM&usp=sharing

This makes me think I've configured something incorrectly. Can anyone spot it?

Sample WKT:

```
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((11.0959798314622 6.46039688549521 0,11.885913117052 5.85981372972084 0,11.6611675157088 5.56421098165167 0,10.8708850668735 6.16452289633918 0,11.0959798314622 6.46039688549521 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((11.885913117052 5.85981372972084 0,11.0959798314622 6.46039688549521 0,11.3224760481292 6.75811300197837 0,12.1123181897999 6.15759914256564 0,11.885913117052 5.85981372972084 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((11.5466005766636 7.05271167221563 0,12.3363525288016 6.45226638354819 0,12.1123181897999 6.15759914256564 0,11.3224760481292 6.75811300197837 0,11.5466005766636 7.05271167221563 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((12.3363525288016 6.45226638354819 0,11.5466005766636 7.05271167221563 0,11.7764387175175 7.35482055386346 0,12.5660981809189 6.75444558401706 0,12.3363525288016 6.45226638354819 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((12.0073425546073 7.65833023129213 0,12.7984300880318 7.06002642651748 0,12.5660981809189 6.75444558401706 0,11.7764387175175 7.35482055386346 0,12.0073425546073 7.65833023129213 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((12.7984300880318 7.06002642651748 0,12.0073425546073 7.65833023129213 0,12.232087222072 7.95374403812074 0,13.0236497939066 7.35625275343114 0,12.7984300880318 7.06002642651748 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((12.4618565878502 8.25576251892767 0,13.2512402335275 7.65559725220707 0,13.0236497939066 7.35625275343114 0,12.232087222072 7.95374403812074 0,12.4618565878502 8.25576251892767 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((13.2512402335275 7.65559725220707 0,12.4618565878502 8.25576251892767 0,12.6819923681615 8.54511821138774 0,13.470326977221 7.94375703426402 0,13.2512402335275 7.65559725220707 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((12.9075850363348 8.84164744281931 0,13.6967905731785 8.24161942134774 0,13.470326977221 7.94375703426402 0,12.6819923681615 8.54511821138774 0,12.9075850363348 8.84164744281931 0)))"
"MULTIPOLYGON Z (((14.157865342396 8.84806051755353 0,13.9250314628096 8.5418194421421 0,13.1383077374417 9.14491982213477 0,13.3700411704104 9.44952075323603 0,14.157865342396 8.84806051755353 0)))"
```

Project CRS: 
[image]

Layer CRS:
[image]

Comment: in composer main properties does it says Cache, Render or Rectangle?

Comment: @AntonioLocandro It starts as Cache, but I've tried the other two as well. I also press the `Update Preview` button.

Comment: Can you confirm that the geometry in your layer corresponds to UTM coordinates? It should have x,y's in the hundred thousands.

Comment: @DPierce Our use case is strange in that we store our geometries without a CRS because our geometries represent storage boxes and trucks that move around. We model our geometries in meters, so when displaying the geometries we just needed something that was expecting meters. I have double checked and the project CRS reads: EPSG:32615 and the layer CRS reads: EPSG:32615. Is there something else I could check for you?

Comment: Could you share some sample data? Even a simple WKT - select an object in QGIS ctrl-C (or cmd-C) to copy, and then paste the text here in a comment!

Comment: Did you add in another layer that you know is correct to verify against (load this control layer in first)?

Comment: @Simbamangu I went ahead and included 10 sample geometries in the question. Let me know if that leads you anywhere.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @artwork21 I went ahead and created a simple project and noticed difficulties with polygons around the origin.  I posted the files in the question.  Could you take a look and see if anything catches your eye? Thanks

Comment: I can not see any objects with your test file, but the WKTs work for me. What QGIS version and what OS are you working with?

Comment: @AndreJoost I tried uploading a new qgis file. The features are stored in the shape file that is also on that Google Drive folder (not sure if QGIS automatically imports them). I am using QGIS: 2.2.0-Valmiera and Mac OSX: 10.9.3. I figure I'll get the "test" file working first then work with my real data to try and keep diagnosing as simple as possible.

Comment: Tried this in QGIS 2.2 (OSX 10.9) and had same symptoms - but with QGIS 2.3 there *isn't* a problem with display in the print composer. Bug in 2.2?

Comment: Same here on Windows. Let's assume the error has bin fixed by now.

Comment: I can't get the nightly build to install right now (probably my fault), so I'm good to just mark it as a bug in 2.2.  Should I report this somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

First off your polygon feature is showing up in the Pacific ocean, not sure if that is correct or not?

[image]

Secondly, you are representing a feature that is slightly more in the southern hemisphere using a northern projection/coordinate system EPSG:32615 (UTM Zone 15N).  If you save your polygon layer out as EPSG:32715 (UTM Zone 15S) and load it into QGIS, it works fine in the composer with the project CRS set to EPSG:32715 (UTM Zone 15S).

Comment: I suggest to use EPSG:3857, which is usable worldwide, except in the polar regions.